# Where can be problem? Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection

Tags: help, bridge

I have problem with Tor Browser.

3 Days before everything was ok  - with meek-google. Yesterday and today nothing... " Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection....Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 0.0.2.0:1)."
And report:

```
15.5.2016 20:33:44.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
15.5.2016 20:33:44.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
15.5.2016 20:33:44.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
15.5.2016 20:33:44.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
15.5.2016 20:33:50.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
15.5.2016 20:33:50.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
15.5.2016 20:38:24.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host 46D4A71197B8FA515A826C6B017C522FE264655B at 0.0.2.0:1)
15.5.2016 20:38:24.500 [WARN] 1 connections have failed:
15.5.2016 20:38:24.500 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
```

I tried all bridges and nothing...

Where can be problem? How to solve it?

Communication is thru fortiguard. But before was working.

Thank you
Pavel Tater

Comment: Is your date and time correct and can you access `https://www.google.com` normally?